# XPath 3.0: select nodes by condition (find max child nodes by date)

Tags: xpath-2.0, xpath-3.0

Given XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <c cid="c0" v="100">
        <d did="c00" v="0" dt="2016-01-01" />
        <d did="c01" v="0" dt="2016-02-03" />
        <d did="c02" v="0" dt="2016-01-15" />
    </c>
    <c cid="c1" v="100">
        <d did="c10" v="1" dt="2016-01-01" />
        <d did="c11" v="0" dt="2015-03-03" />
        <d did="c12" v="0" dt="2015-04-15" />
    </c>
</root>
```

I have to find XPath 2.0 or 3.0, which will return to me list of `c` nodes by expression: find maximum `d` node of this `c` children by `dt` attribute (parse it as `date`), and if its `v` attribute value is "0", return the `c` node.

I expect to get a one `c` node (with @cid="c0") as a result, because `/root/c[cid="c1"]/d[@dt="2016-01-01"]/@v` is not equal to 0 (is equal to 1).

I have stuck on this XPath sofar:

```
/root/c[d[max(xs:date(@dt))]/@v="0"]
```

It gives me an error (I'm using Oxygen XML Editor, XPath 3.0):

> XPath failed due to: Effective boolean value is not defined for a
>   sequence starting with an atomic value other than a boolean, number,
>   string, or URI

I suppose this is due to misused `max` function, but cannot get it working.

**UPDATES:**

1. Lets assume that `c` nodes will have `d` children with unique maximum value of their `dt` attributes.
2. I also tried XPath 3.0 expression:

   `/root/c[d[@dt=max(.//@dt/xs:date(.))]/@v="0"]`

but it returned me all nodes (wrong result).

Comment: What to do if node c will have more than one d node with the same maximal dt attribute value and different v attribute values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a shorter and probably more efficient** (the max per a **`<c>`** element is calculated just once) **XPath 2.0 one-liner**:

```
/*/c[max(d/xs:date(@dt)) = d[@v eq '0']/@dt]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: BTW, when I used equal sign `=` instead of `eq` literal in this expression in Oxygen 18 XPath 3 editor, it also worked fine.

Comment: @lospejos, Yes, but in XPath 2.0 the `eq` operator is specifically designed to handle comparissons between atomic values. The purpose of the general comparison operator `=` is to be used in comparissons where at least one of the operands is a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In XQuery the query is quite straight-forward and can be written to only calculate the maximum date once per `c` node:

```
for $c in /root/c
let $max := max($c/d/@dt/xs:date(.))
where $c/d[@dt = $max]/@v = '0'
return $c
```

In XPath you can write the query to (at least conceptually) calculate it once per `d` node and hope that the result is either optimized by the processor or fast enough anyway:

```
/root/c[d[@dt = max(../d/@dt/xs:date(.))]/@v = '0']
```

You can also use the [`let` expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-let-expressions) of XPath to recover the explicit pre-computation:

```
/root/c[
  let $max := max(d/@dt/xs:date(.))
  return d[@dt = $max]/@v = '0'
]
```

Comment: Leo Wörteler, there is in fact an XPath 2.0 expression that calculates the maximum just once per a `<c>` element.

Comment: You could abuse a `for`, `some`, or `every` expression to iterate over a single item and thus emulate the `let`, is that what you're refering to? **Edit:** Oh, I see. Very nice!